# OneDrive query returns empty array

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I am currently working on a solution that is accessing OneDrive in Office 365 using Microsoft Graph.  I am using the `adal4j` library to handle authentication and have configured the app in `portal.azure.com`.

My question relates the call to get the children for a specified drive.  I am using a query similar to the one shown below, as I want to get folders and files at the root level of a specified users drive:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/*user id*/drives/*drive id*/root/children
```

When I login to the Graph Explorer and execute the query, I get a json result showing the root folder contents for the drive and user specified. All works as expected.

When I call it from my java application, the JSON node `value` is empty (`[]`).

Initially my thought was, because the Graph Explorer uses a different app id in the portal it was possibly something to do with access rights.  However, I successfully read user profiles in our O365 tenant, the drive id's for each user, and if I execute the following:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/*user id*/drives/*drive id*/root/search(q='')
```

It provides me a complete list of all of the folders, sub folders etc within the appropriate user's drive.

Therefore, making me think this is a bug with the Graph query I am attempting to use rather than an authorization issue, but, that wouldn't explain why it works in the Graph Explorer.

The same java method is used for all calls, and the url is passed in as a parameter.

Comment: My first reaction is that it must be permissions, but in that case it would be strange that search worked. Could you crack open your access token using https://jwt.ms and update your question to include the `scp` values? Also, is the caller the owner of the drive in question?

Comment: Yeah.  That was my thought too, but cant understand how just about every other call works correctly.  Token SCP values are :- Directory.AccessAsUser.All User.Read User.ReadBasic.All

Comment: OK, found where to add more settings.  Have now set the scp properties, to AllSites.Manage AllSites.Read AllSites.Write Directory.AccessAsUser.All Directory.Read.All Directory.ReadWrite.All Files.Read Files.Read.All Files.Read.Selected Files.ReadWrite Files.ReadWrite.All Files.ReadWrite.AppFolder Files.ReadWrite.Selected MyFiles.Read MyFiles.Write offline_access openid Sites.Read.All User.Read User.ReadBasic.All.  However, when I list the contents using the above query in graph I get all the appropriate sub folders, but, when I execute remotely I only get the documents folder ?

Answer (score 0):

Just to follow up, the azure portal app permissions has the capability of adding permissions for the graph api.  This was, indeed the problem.  It would appear that the search was ignoring the permission and successfully reading the data whereas the /children call was honouring the security model.  This caused a lot of confusion, but is now resolved.

Thanks Marc for your help.